# Listening Laravel event from different Laravel Project

Tags: laravel-5.5, pusher, laravel-echo

I have two different Laravel projects:
**newera.student** and **newera.tutor**

**When I fire a broadcast event from newera.tutor project**, I would like to **listen to that broadcast on newera.student project**.

How to achieve that.

I am using Laravel echo and pusher-js on the client

Answer (score 1):

I just did it. The two project must have the same pusher credentials.